# How to change textLabel outside CollectionView when cell is clicked in Swift 4?

Tags: ios, label, swift4, cell, collectionview

can you help me how can I change text in label, which is outside the CollectionView but in the same ViewController, when cell is clicked? I need different text in label with different cell.

P.S. I'm new in swift :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the cell's didSelectAt function you can retrieve the other cell based on that indexPath and then you can update the label in that cell:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let otherCell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: IndexPath(item: otherCellsIndexItem, section: otherCellsIndexSection)) as! YourCollectionViewCell
        otherCell.label.text = "New Text"
        }
    }
```

EDIT 1: The label is outside the collection view, then:

```
class YourView {
  ...
  @IBOutlet weak var yourLabel: UILabel!
  // or
  var yourLabel: UILabel?

  ...
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        self.label.text = "New Text"
        // or, if it's UILabel?, then:
        self.label?.text = "New Text"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But Label isn't in any cell, it's outside, in viewController.

Comment: In this case I guess you have it as an IBOutlet or simply variable in your class. So, simply access that and change the text. See my edit.